# codeigniter: fetch data from database by ID

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

[The name and the description of each form should be different from each other and should be able to reflect on what's written on the database. As you can see, my code keeps reading the same details. What should I do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4oP1.jpg)

**MY MODEL**

```
<?php

defined ('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Agrivest_model extends CI_Model{ 

public function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->database();       
}
public function get_category_tb(){
  $this->db->from('category_tb');
  $this->db->limit(1);
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
}
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
defined ('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class Agrivest extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){

parent::__construct();
 $this->load->helper('url');
 $this->load->model('agrivest_model'); }
 public function index(){
 $data['category_tb'] = $this->agrivest_model->get_category_tb();
 $this->load->view('landing_page', $data); }
```

**MY VIEW**

```
<?php foreach ($category_tb as $post){?>
<p class="category_description"><?php echo $post->category_description; ?> </p>
```

Comment: but where you're passing the ID

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function index($cat_id){
  $data['category_tb'] = $this->agrivest_model->get_category_tb($cat_id);
  $this->load->view('landing_page', $data);
}

public function get_category_tb($cat_id){
   $query=$this->db->get_where('category_tb', array('id' => $cat_id), 1, 1);
   return $query->result();
}
```

don't forget to pass parameter category_id in your url